# Relation between sample standard deviation from data and maximum likelihood estimates

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-deviation, likelihood

This is my data:-

```
c(3164, 3362, 4435, 3542, 3578, 4529)
```

I estimated its sample mean and standard deviation via `mean` & `sd` functions and got the following results

```
mu
[1] 3768.333
sigma
[1] 572.859
```

now I generated the parameter values that maximize the log likelihood assuming the underlying data is generated from a normal distribution using the following code and  `optim` function

```
op <- function(para){
    loglik <- sum(log(dnorm(x,para[1],para[2])))
    -loglik
}

optim(c(3200,570),op)

OUTPUT:-

$par
[1] 3768.2043  522.9118

$value
[1] 46.0705

$counts
function gradient 
      49       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

My question is shouldn't the sample sd **572.859** be the parameter value that **maximises the log-likelihood** rather than **522.9118**, and if not then how can we assume that the sample sd is an **unbiased estimator of the population sd**?

Comment: Here the MLE for $\sigma^2$ is biased since it divides by $n$, whereas the unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ divides by $n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum likelihood estimator to which you refer (for a Gaussian likelihood) can be derived as $\hat\sigma =\sqrt{
\dfrac{
\sum_{i=1}^N\left(
X_i-\bar X\right)^2
}{
N
}
}$.

The function you’ve called divides by $N-1$. This is because dividing by $N-1$ and not taking the square root results in an unbiased estimator of variance, and then the square root of the unbiased estimator of variance is taken as a fairly natural step to estimate the square root of the variance (though this is a biased estimator of standard deviation by Jensen’s inequality).

That is, the `sd` function is not calculating according to maximum likelihood estimation.

If you increase the sample size, you should see the two results get closer and closer together.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't use MLE to estimate parameter values? And if so how can I estimate it given some data?

Comment: Also then for gradient descent methods when can we trust their results if in some cases as above they can give biased estimates of parameter values?

Comment: @RishavDhariwal There’s nothing inherently wrong with biased estimators. In fact, many popular estimators (e.g., ridge regression) go out of their way to introduce a bit bias in hopes of scoring major improvements in other estimator properties, such as variance.

Comment: I understand that but still I would want to know when applying MLE could introduce bias in my estimates and for which ones should i be careful. For example, here I am getting a biased estimate of SD but other distributions have many different parameters like degree of freedom etc is there any test I can perform on my estimates for this?

Comment: @RishavDhariwal “Bias” doesn’t mean the estimator gives you the incorrect value. In fact, you can be basically certain that, no matter how you estimate a parameter, your estimate is incorrect. With that in mind, I do not really understand what you’re asking. Perhaps it would be worth fleshing out your inquiry into a full question to post.